# Подсветка синтаксиса markdown при помощи pygments в html

Tags: html, css, python, markdown

Я хочу 'перевести' markdown в html, и команда (1)

```
python -m markdown input.md > output.html
```

c этим прекрасно справляется. Но помимо этого, я хочу сделать подстветку синтаксиса. Для этого я хотел использовать библиотеку pygments и codehilite для markdown'a. Я использовал такую комманду(2) для того что бы перевести markdown в html с прописанными классами для каждого из тегов:

```
python -m markdown -x codehilite some_markdown.md > body.html
```

и команду (3) для генерации css:

```
pygmentize -S default -f html > codehilite.css
```

команда (3) работает прекрасно и css генерируется, но команда (2) делает тоже самое что и (1), я получаю на выходе простой html без классов, вследсттвие чего css не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Окей, я нашел решение. Я решил свою проблему путем написания кода:

```
from markdown import markdown
content = '*some markdown code here*'
result = markdown(content, extension=['codehilite'])
```

в итоге в `result` будет html разметка с нужными мне классами у тегов.